# How to get Sonar to export test stats?

Tags: ant, junit, sonarqube, emma

I have the following Sonar Ant target defined:

```
<target name='sonar'>
    <property name='sonar.sources' value='${src.dir}'/>
    <property name='sonar.tests' value='${test.src.dir}'/>
    <property name='sonar.binaries' value='build/classes'/>
    <path id='jars'>
        <fileset dir='${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib' includes='*.jar'/>
        <fileset dir='build/lib/test' includes='*.jar'/>
    </path>
    <pathconvert property='sonar.libraries' refid='jars' pathsep=','/>

    <exec executable='p4' outputproperty='p4.P4CLIENT'>
        <arg value='set'/>
        <arg value='P4CLIENT'/>
    </exec>
    <propertyregex
            property='p4client'
            input='${p4.P4CLIENT}'
            regexp='P4CLIENT=([^ ]+) *.*'
            replace='\1'/>
    <propertyregex
            property='sonar.timestamp'
            input='${build.time}'
            regexp='_'
            replace='T'/>
    <sonar:sonar key='com.netflix:${module.name}' version='${p4client}@${sonar.timestamp}' xmlns:sonar='antlib:org.sonar.ant'/>

    <property name='sonar.dynamicAnalysis' value='reuseReports'/>
    <property name='sonar.emma.reportPath' value='${coverage.dir}'/>
</target>
```

When I run 'ant sonar' and bring up Sonar in my browser, I see info about the classes in the src directory, but nothing about the stuff in the test directory.

If I add ${test.src.dir} to sonar.sources and not set sonar.tests, I see some info about the test classes, but Sonar still reports 0 Test Successes.

How do I get it so I can drill down to each test method and their stats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property 'sonar.surefire.reportsPath' needs to be defined before the definition of the sonar target.

The following definition gets the test info exported (although it's still not exporting coverage info):

```
<property name='sonar.surefire.reportsPath' value='${test.dir}'/>

<property name='sonar.dynamicAnalysis' value='reuseReports'/>
<property name='sonar.emma.reportPath' value='${coverage.report.dir}'/>

<target name='sonar'>
    <property name='sonar.sources' value='${src.dir}'/>
    <property name='sonar.tests' value='${test.src.dir}'/>
    <property name='sonar.binaries' value='${build.dir}'/>
    <path id='jars'>
        <fileset dir='${env.JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib' includes='*.jar'/>
        <fileset dir='${ivy.lib.dir}/test' includes='*.jar'/>
    </path>
    <pathconvert property='sonar.libraries' refid='jars' pathsep=','/>

    <exec executable='p4' outputproperty='p4.P4CLIENT'>
        <arg value='set'/>
        <arg value='P4CLIENT'/>
    </exec>
    <propertyregex
            property='p4client'
            input='${p4.P4CLIENT}'
            regexp='P4CLIENT=([^ ]+) *.*'
            replace='\1'/>
    <propertyregex
            property='sonar.timestamp'
            input='${build.time}'
            regexp='_'
            replace='T'/>

    <sonar:sonar key='com.netflix:${module.name}' version='${p4client}@${sonar.timestamp}' xmlns:sonar='antlib:org.sonar.ant'/>
</target>
```

Comment: Hi I'm having a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267948/sonarqube-test-coverage-report-for-android-built-with-ant) but not quite the same... how are you guys getting a .emma file out?

Comment: We've actually stopped using Sonar and will be building our own build data repository.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else that runs across this issue, I finally got Sonar to report on our Emma Code coverage.  The first problem was that the Emma plugin did not come with the version of Sonar I was using (3.1.1).  I had to [download it](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+Emma+Plugin) and install it to the `extensions/plugins` directory of Sonar and restart it.

Then I had to set the following properties in my build.xml:

```
<property name="sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin" value="emma" />
<property name="sonar.emma.reportPath" value="${coverage.dir}" />
```

After this, I atleast saw the following output after running the Sonar ant task:

```
[sonar:sonar] 13:41:49.705 WARN        org.sonar.INFO - No coverage (*.ec) file found in /my/local/path
[sonar:sonar] 13:41:49.708 WARN        org.sonar.INFO - No metadata (*.em) file found in /my/local/path
```

After some digging, I found that inside of the [Sonar Emma plugin](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins/sonar-emma-plugin/1.2.1/org/sonar/plugins/emma/EmmaProcessor.java), it is hard-coded to look for a .ec (coverage) file and a .em (metadata) file.  Unfortunately, my coverage file had a .emma extension as did my metadata file and I was unable to rename them as it would break other functionality.  So I wrote the following Ant task to copy the files to match the naming standard that the Sonar Emma plugin expects.

```
<target name="createEmmaFilesWithSonarNamingStandard" depends="defineAntContribTasks">
    <if>
        <available file="${coverage.dir}/metadata.emma" />
        <then>
            <copyfile src="${coverage.dir}/metadata.emma" dest="${coverage.dir}/metadata.em" />
        </then>
    </if>
    <if>
        <available file="${coverage.dir}/coverage.emma" />
        <then>
            <copyfile src="${coverage.dir}/coverage.emma" dest="${coverage.dir}/coverage.ec" />
        </then>
    </if>
</target>
```

After running this again, I came across a new problem:

```
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: java.io.IOException: cannot read [/my/local/path/build/coverage/metadata.em]: created by another EMMA version [2.0.5312]
```

After some more digging, I found that the Sonar Emma 1.0.1 plugin was compiled against Emma 2.0.5312 and the Sonar Emma 1.1 and 1.2.x against Emma version 2.1.5320 as stated on the [Sonar Emma plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+Emma+Plugin) page.

I downloaded the 2.1.5320 version of Emma, replaced both [emma.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/emma/emma/2.1.5320) as well as [emma_ant.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/emma/emma_ant/2.1.5320) in my Ant lib directory.  After a clean re-compile and test, I was able to re-run the Sonar Ant task and have my code coverage reflected on Sonar.